# Porqué el nombre del acceso directo app es el nombre de la .apk

Tags: android, apk, android-manifest

He buscado y buscado donde cambiar el nombre del acceso directo de mi app y no encuentro donde.

Esto me lleva a pensar que la solución es cambiar el nombre de la apk y subirla de nuevo. En la `Google Play Store` todo es correcto

Comment: No es así, el nombre que se mantiene es el nombre del proyecto

Comment: Tienes razón el nombre del proyecto es el mismo que el de la .apk. Gracias

Comment: Cambiando el nombre del .apk no influye en el cambio de la aplicación, el nombre que se debe cambiar es en el AndroidManifest.xml o dentro del build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

El nombre de la apk lo puedes cambiar en el **AndroidManifest**. Dentro de:

```
<aplication
    android:label="elnombrequequieras">
    ...
</aplication>
```

Con eso debería bastar.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes cambiar el nombre directamente desde la propiedad [android:label](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element?hl=es-419#label)

```
 android:label="nombre aplicación"
```

pero lo ideal que este nombre se obtenga desde una referencia en tu archivo `strings.xml`:

```
 android:label="@string/app_name"
```

incluso ahora lo puedes realizar desde el `build.gradle` usando también el valor definido dentro de `strings.xml`, pero incluso puedes definir diferentes nombres para versiones de debug o release, agregando estos valores dentro de `strings.xml`:

```
 buildTypes {
    admin {
       resValue "string", "app_name", "@string/app_name"
    }
    release {
        resValue "string", "app_name", "@string/app_name_release"
    }
    debug {
        resValue "string", "app_name", "@string/app_name_debug"
    }
}
```

---

> Esto me lleva a pensar que la solución es cambiar el nombre de la apk
>   y subirla de nuevo. En la play store todo es correcto

**Si cambias el nombre del .apk esto no puede cambiar el nombre de la aplicación.**

Comment: muy interesante lo del los nombres en el build.gradle

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag para generar una app con nombre diferente y no te pregunten "es de debug o es de produccion" haha :)

Comment: El problema es que es una aplicación híbrida. Con lo que me puede llevar menos tiempo reproducir el proyecto con el nombre que quiero que tenga el acceso directo